# Typing Text Script with unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, unordered

I have been using the typewriter.js effect for a while. Works great. now I want to use it with a `unodered list (ul)`, but if I use any `tags`, the effect does not want to work. Any help?

Heres the js script I'm working with:
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex10/text5.htm

Example:

With the example javascript from link and this:

```
<p id="aboutskills">Windows 2008 Servers</p>
<script type="text/javascript">

        new TypingText(document.getElementById("aboutskills"));

        TypingText.runAll();
        </script>
```

This works!

But this:

```
      <p id="aboutskills">
            <ul class="skills">
                <li>Windows 2008 Servers</li>
                <li>Network Analysis</li>
                <li>Bash, Batch, Powershell scripting</li>
                <li>C#, VB .Net</li>
            </ul>
      <p>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    new TypingText(document.getElementById("aboutskills"));

    TypingText.runAll();
    </script>
```

Does NOT Work!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is because you can't have `<ul>` element inside `<p>`.

If you inspect your HTML in Chrome DevTools or Firebug you should see something like this (BTW you have no `</p>`):

```
<p id="aboutskills"></p>
<ul class="skills">
    <li>Windows 2008 Servers</li>
    <li>Network Analysis</li>
    <li>Bash, Batch, Powershell scripting</li>
    <li>C#, VB .Net</li>
</ul>
<p></p>
```

Read more here:
https://developers.whatwg.org/grouping-content.html#the-p-element

So, you can just change `<p>` into `<div>` and everything will work properly:
http://jsfiddle.net/8cd88fn0/